# Is there any way to prevent Mutons from counter-attacking against melee?

Tags: xcom-2

It's possible to break enemy troops out of an overwatch state but is there a way to stop Mutons from counterattacking when melee attacked?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this but flashbangs disable many abilities- they might be worth a try.

Comment: Standard answer for all XCOM-2 tactical combat problems. "How do I beat the mission..." *Flashbang!* "But what if..." *Flashbang!!* "but..." *Flashbang!!!*

Comment: @philipp "What are advent burgers..." Flashbang!

Comment: Don't use melee against mutons. Flank them and use shotgun.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Flashbangs, according to this [XCOM Wiki page](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Flashbang_Grenade_(XCOM_2)) (emphasis mine):

> Prevents use of any and all special abilities - Stun Lancers will not
>   use their blades, Officers will not use grenades, **Mutons cannot even
>   counter-attack in melee**, if Disoriented.

I have not been brave enough to confirm this for myself, however.

In addition, some [Psi Operatives](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Psi_Operative_(XCOM_2)) abilities (Insanity and Void Rift) may Disorient enemies for the same effect, but this is somewhat less reliable.

Comment: I assume this would prevent a Shield Bearer from activating its shield whilst stunned/disorientated?

Comment: @DavidYell depends entirely on the ability, whether or not it has an exception set for disoriented.

Comment: @DavidYell: iirc not _every_ skill is disabled by a flashbang. An officer can still mark targets. IIRC, a viper can still tongue lash/poision spit (it was one of the two). A shield bearer might still be able to do his shield since it's not an offensive skill in and of itself.

Comment: It is weird. I can swear I slashed many mutons without any repercussions. And I rarely use flashbangs. So it must not be a guaranteed counter-attack.

Answer (score 6):

Psi-Powers. 
If you can disorient your opponent (There is a Psi-power that can do this however I forget it's name right now.) most of their abilities such as Dodge and Counter won't work.

This is in addition to the other answer about flashbangs.

Comment: I did consider this when writing my answer - I've not done a lot with Psi powers yet, but there is a list of XCOM 2 Psi Abilities on the XCOM wiki at http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Psi_Operative_(XCOM_2). From there, it sounds like Insanity has a chance to Disorient, but not reliably?

Comment: @raveturned that's the one seems to work about 1/3 of the time. I'm pretty sure the massive sphere one has a chance to cause it too. (That might only be when enemies attack you though)

Comment: Ah, Void Rift has "a chance to inflict insanity on all targets in the storm" - assume that's the one you mean. :)

Comment: @raveturned that's it! Sorry about the cryptic responses I'm in work and can't google D: